# Cordova InAppBrowser - Cannot display PDF file due to there is no build-in PDF vierer in Android

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser, pdf-viewer

How to support displaying PDF files in App in Android without install third party App manually by user?

I used below Cordova InAppBrowser (to support iOS and Android) code but failed for Android:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(__HTTP_FILE_LINK__, '_blank', 
  'enableViewPortScale=yes,location=no,toolbartranslucent=no,
  closebuttoncaption=Done,usewkwebview=yes,transitionstyle=crossdissolve,
  hardwareback=no,hideurlbar=yes,hidespinner=yes,hidenavigationbuttons=yes');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to take a look at this [repository](https://github.com/digistorm/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/tree/master/src/android): integrating that and adding the download class, make the download of pdf work on Android